# Amazon FPS - aggregate multiple payments?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This has to do w/ Amazon's Flexible Payment service:

In order to try to save transactions costs I would like to aggregate all of my customers' payments & then settle them in a single pay request at the end of the day. Is this possible?

For instance, in the same day, Bob buys something for $25, Susan buys something for $30, Tim buys something for $15. Instead of sending a pay request for EACH person immediately after they buy, I want to send a SINGLE pay request at the end of the day.

The examples Amazon gives for Aggregated Payments only lists multiple payments from the SAME user, not different users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, because the fees cover the processing of customers credit and debit cards, so they need to be applied to the balance of each customer.

You could still use aggregate payments to send a pay request at the end of the day for each user (in case they buy something else), but each credit card needs to be charged and you can't combine those charges.